# Using absolute position to achieve four simple layouts

Tags: css

I'm trying to get four different layouts, some text with either another bit of text to the left, to the right, above or below.

I have this code:

```
<div>
  <span class="icon">H</span>
  <span class="text">Hello</span>
</div>
```

Then this CSS

```
div { background: grey; position: absolute;}
.icon {font-family: calibri; position: absolute;}
//.text {padding-left: 15px;} .icon {left: 0;} // Icon left of text
//.text {padding-right: 15px;} .icon {right: 0;} //Icon right of text
//.text { padding-top: 15px; } .icon {top: 0;} // Icon top of text
//.text { padding-bottom: 15px; } .icon {bottom: 0;} // Icon bottom of text
```

Then depending on which one of the last four lines I uncomment out should determines the position of icon text in relation to the main text. However, it doesn't seem to work, and I'm only able to really achieve the "Icon left of text" position.

Can anyone explain where I am going wrong.

Comment: In css, you cannot use single comments (`//`). only the multiline version works (`/* ... */`). As such, all 4 lines are applied (in cascading order) and effectively the last one will always apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two issues that are effecting the output:

### Incorrect comments

CSS only supports `/**/` comments and not `//`, this means that the browser is getting confused and is implementing/ignoring rules.

### `.text` and `.icon` are `inline` elements

`.text` and `.icon` are `span`s which makes them `inline` elements by default. `inline` elements don't support `top` and `bottom` `padding` so your top and bottom rules will not have the desired effect. This can be rectifed by making `.text` and `.icon` `block` elements instead.

```css
div {
  background: grey;
  position: absolute;
}
.icon {
  font-family: calibri;
  position: absolute;
}
span {
  display: block;
}

.left {
  top: 0;
}
.left .text {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.left .icon {
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  top: 3em;
}
.right .text {
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.right .icon {
  right: 0;
}


.top {
  top: 6em;
}
.top .text {
  padding-top: 15px;
}
.top .icon {
  top: 0;
}


.bottom {
  top: 9em
}
.bottom .text {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.bottom .icon {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <span class="icon">H</span>
  <span class="text">Hello</span>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <span class="icon">H</span>
  <span class="text">Hello</span>
</div>
<div class="top">
  <span class="icon">H</span>
  <span class="text">Hello</span>
</div>
<div class="bottom">
  <span class="icon">H</span>
  <span class="text">Hello</span>
</div>
```